# HDFS Unit testing in Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing unit test in Spark 1.6 application and have to mock a HDFS. Is using the MiniDFSCluster https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDevelopUnitTests as described here. I don't see any examples in the current Spark 1.6 code that use MiniDFSCluster.

Comment: did you try any of the posted solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Below is a snippet showing how to setup and use the Cluster.

```
    val conf = new HdfsConfiguration()
    val testDataCluster = new File("/var/path", "root")
    conf.set(MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, testDataCluster.getAbsolutePath)
    conf.setInt("dfs.blocksize", 512)
    conf.setInt("dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size", 512)
    val dfs =  new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf).build()
    dfs.waitActive()
    val fileSystem: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = dfs.getFileSystem
    fileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(false, new Path(sourceDir),
      new Path(hdfsDir))
```

some of the dependencies that you might require are (the below are in sbt module definition format)

```
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.7.2" % "test",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.2" % "test",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.7.2" % "test" classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.2" % "test" classifier "tests"
```

Comment: This solution worked beautiful in my SBT project with Hadoop 2.8.3. I tried before adding the dependency "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-minicluster" % "2.8.3" % "test" as suggested in many other places, but  this did not work, my sbt was not importing the HDFS test classes.

Comment: Yes wasted days over `2.7.2`, `2.7.1` and even the latest `3.3.0` version. Version `2.8.3` works like a charm! I am using  it with spark 3.0.2