# Spark streaming and mocking hdfs

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, cucumber, hdfs

There is a requirement to implement a test for a spark streaming code. This particular code  is running in a separate jvm by using [this library](https://github.com/ViktorC/PP4J)
And the input for above application is hdfs. I've started MiniDFSCluster like in this [example (java version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047559/hdfs-unit-testing-in-spark-1-6) 
But i don't think it will work because these are in two different JVMs.

What would be the best approach to mock the hdfs input if i were to successfully test the spark streaming code.

I explained above scenario generally. The real requirement is to implement a successful [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) test.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to mock hdfs you can run Spark in local mode and specify paths  like "file:///foo/bar" - the local filesystem will then be used instead of hdfs.

Comment: I"ve tried that some commands like org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem delete() doesn't work :(

Comment: It is worth persisting as it should work - at least it has for me, including deletes.

Comment: Using FileSystem.newInstance that takes a URI got deletes working, according to my notes.

Comment: There is no delete thats taking a URI :(

Comment: FileSystem fs = FileSystem.newInstance(uri, config); ... fs.delete(path, true);